# Issue with while loop in game.

Tags: python, while-loop, adventure

I'm making a game and it has different tiles obviously. But I've come to an issue in my main Game while loop.

```
def play():
    player  = player1()
    while True:
        room = ClubWorld.tile_at(player.x, player.y)
        print(room.intro_text())
        choose_action(room, player)
```

Example of a Tile in my game:

```
class GirlTile(MapTile):
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.meet_girl = Girls()
        super().__init__(x, y)

    def intro_text(self):
        return "Hey whats up, my name is {}".format(self.meet_girl.name)
```

This loop keeps going as long as I'm on a game tile. It produces the available actions you have and lets the other functions know your position. it also outputs that tiles intro text, where my problem lies. I want the game to only output the intro text upon entry into a tile, once that happens i only want it to display the actions available. Suggestions?

Comment: what is the problem with the loop here? with the piece of code you provided, it is difficult to make any suggestion.

Comment: Was hoping there was a way loop thru once with all three function and then only loop thru with room, and choose_action until the room has changed. Asking a lot I know

Comment: `if new_room: print(room.intro_text())` and now you have to find method to recognize new room - you could use ie `player.old_x, player.old_y`. Or `old_room` to remember previous room.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep `previous_room` and compare with `room`:

```
def play():
    player  = player1()
    previous_room = None
    while True:
        room = ClubWorld.tile_at(player.x, player.y)
        if room != previous_room:
            print(room.intro_text())
            previous_room = room
        choose_action(room, player)
```

Or keep player previous position `previous_x`, `previous_y` and compare with new position

```
def play():
    player = player1()
    previous_x = None
    previous_y = None
    while True:
        if player.x != previous_x or player.y != previous_y :
            room = ClubWorld.tile_at(player.x, player.y)
            print(room.intro_text())
            previous_x = player.x
            previous_y = player.y
        choose_action(room, player)
```